# Mass Delete empty sub folders in Office 365 via Power Shell

Tags: powershell, office365

In Office 365, when sub folders of the Inbox of their mailbox are moved to the Online Archive, it leaves the Folder/Subfolder empty in the mailbox.

Can that folder be purged without affecting the Online archive? A

nd if so, how can I purge empty sub folders via PowerShell in O365?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, it's expected that you attempt to code this yourself. I would suggest you do some research on your issue (maybe try the search box at the top of the page) and make an attempt at writing some code yourself. If/when you come across any issues with your code, ask again and explain what you have tried, and why it did not work for you. See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) for help with asking a good question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to find all Empty Folders :

Get-MailboxFolderStatistics user@domain.com | Where {$_.ItemsInFolder -eq 0} | Select Identity

Deletion can be done using EWS

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exovoice/2017/01/12/delete-a-list-of-folders-from-specific-mailboxes-with-ews-managed-api-2-2-and-application-impersonation-in-exchange-online/